# PHP How to Ready Body of File SENT to Script

Tags: php

I have a client who needs to send cXML data to my script. They are sending it in the body of the request instead of as a POST request. How can I read the data in the body of what they send?

Comment: Could you post more details?

Comment: The raw POST body should be contained in the stream [`php://input`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).